# Debug Mode is not working in laravel on different environment

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, laravel-5.6

If I use the below-given lines in the .env file, debugging is working

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```

But if I use

```
APP_ENV=test
APP_DEBUG=true
```

debugging is not working

If I change the `App_Env` value from **local** to any other value debugging is not working,
I can't use local as `App_Env` value at all times, because I use this same application in more than one system for dev, test, and production. some functionalities in the application are differs based on the environment.

I want to debug on both dev and test application systems.

Comment: Do not forget to run the command php artisan config:clear after you have made the changes to the .env file

Comment: yes, I did that even though it's not working

Comment: Try to put `env('APP_ENV')` and `env('APP_DEBUG')` in tinker, and see the result

Comment: OK, what if I use Apache server for the execution